# Suppose that n women check their coats at a concert

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a seemingly difficult algorithm that I must construct, and I'm not sure where to even start. Here it is:

Suppose that n women check their coats at a concert. However, at the end of the night,
the attendant has lost the claim checks and does not know which coat belongs to whom.
All of the women came dressed in black coats that were nearly identical, but of different
sizes. The attendant can have a woman try a coat, and find out whether the coat fits
(meaning it belongs to that woman), or the coat is too big, or the coat is too small.
However, the attendant cannot compare the sizes of two coats directly, or compare the
sizes of two women directly. Describe how the attendant can determine which coat
belongs to which woman in expected O(n log n) time.

I've thought of ways to do this, but none come close to O(n log n) time. 
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: He can just ask them. That's linear

Comment: Assuming you don't put a mutex lock on the coat rack, you can parallelize the operation across the n women for linear time as well.

Comment: @dan-klasson That wouldn't result in (n log n) time

Comment: @EJoshuaS So the reasoning this question is "Too broad" is because I didn't give a large enough background following this sentence: "I've thought of ways to do this, but none come close to O(n log n) time"? Also, the phrasing I used after that sentence?

Comment: @DillonDavis The parallelism idea is clever. Just have all the women select a coat at random, arrange them in a ring, and have them try it on. If it fits, leave with it. If it doesn't fit pass it left. Abuse the fact that the women can be processors instead of the attendant.

Comment: @HarrisonBergman The problem is that you don't describe anything you actually tried yourself, nor do you ask a specific question, so it sounds like you're expecting us to do it for you. The question would be greatly improved if, for example, you could give more details on the ways you thought of doing this that didn't work out.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I didn't really think it would be necessary to explain that I've tried doing this linearly. Wouldn't that seem immediately obvious? I'm just confused as to how asking how I would even start this question is a waste of everyone's time. I wasn't asking for the entire question to be finished for me, I just wanted some guidance on how else I can think about it. User moreOn understood where I was coming from, and gave a very useful answer... ironically enough.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this ends up kind of like quicksort.

Have all the women try on one coat, then you have the women grouped into smaller than that coat, and larger than that coat. And one to whom that coat fits.

Now have that woman who the first coat fits try on every other coat to find if it's larger or smaller. In linear time you now have two distinct groups that you can perform this procedure recursively on.

This is much like quicksort, where the partition step is linear time and produces 2 groups to perform quicksort on recursively. With random pivot there's expected O(nlogn) run time.